# Why are block sizes limited by page size in Linux?

Tags: linux, filesystems, linux-kernel

In many (all?) file systems that Linux uses, including ext2/3/4, the maximum block size is the page size of the architecture Linux is running on, ie. 4KiB on x86. Why is there this limit? Might this limit ever be removed?

Comment: I don't think they hanged together, but maybe somebody knows more. Until then, here is a bookmarking and an upvote. Do you know any filesystem whose block size were bigger as 4k?

Comment: @PeterHorvath: XFS (not on Linux), BSD's FFS, ZFS (although that one's a bit weird), VxFS (not sure on Linux), UFS on Solaris/Sparc (but that one's "cheating" - 8k block size but 8k page size too)

Comment: @Mat Uhm, thanks. This makes the question really interesting.

Comment: https://lwn.net/Articles/469805/ - "Raising the filesystem block size in the kernel is a dauntingly difficult task involving major changes to memory management, the page cache, and more." - so the answer to your question is probably a bit complicated...

Comment: I can see that having the 2 the some would probably make things more efficient.

Comment: I wonder what happens if you make a large block file-system on a system with large pages. Then move it to, and mount it on, a system with smaller pages.

Comment: But Linux also supports VFAT and NTFS. Does it not support any non-page-size blocks there? They seem to be quite easy to create in Windows — and for VFAT they are in fact quite frequent on very large media.

Comment: @richard: fails to mount (at least for ext*), the fs driver does some sanity checks thankfully.

Comment: @mat, My comment was a rhetorical question, hence the lack of question mark (thanks for clarifying though). I was wondering about compatibility for removable (and removed) media, used on systems with huge page sizes.